# inner product space and gram matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question from my proffesor that I can not figure it out.

V will be inner product system above R2.

Let E some basis with the gram matrix (E={v1,v2})
This is the gram matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & -1\\
  -1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
  {(v_{1},v_{1})} & {(v_{1},v_{2})}\\
  {(v_{2},v_{1})} & {(v_{2},v_{2})}\\
  \end{pmatrix}

Let T:V->V be a linear map with a matrix represent T according to basis E

\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2\\
  2 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}

is T is self adjoint ?

well first of all according to gram matrix it is very easy to see that E is not a orthonormal set and therefore T* is necessarily equal to the matrix of T with a transpose and conjunction.

So where can I go from here because I can not assume that the inner product is the standard one and therefore I do not know How to look for it, if exists ?

and if it is not exist how can I proof that if I do not know inner product and by that I can not find the adjoint

Comment: Symmetric matrices correspond to self-adjoint operators.

Comment: @Daved The matrix of $T$ given here corresponds to a non-orthonormal basis of $V$. So you can't read whether $T$ is self-adjoint on this matrix like that.

Comment: @julien okay, should add:"in orthonormal basis".

Comment: You should have edited your first question, where several of us took the time to respond carefully!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us call $P$ the matrix of the basis $E$ expressed in an orthonormal basis, so that
$$
P^*P=\pmatrix{2&-1\\-1&1}=Q
$$
and, if $A$ denotes the matrix of $T$ in the same orthonormal basis,
$$
P^{-1}AP=\pmatrix{1&2\\2&1}=B.
$$
So the question amounts to: do we have $A^*=A$? Now, note that $B^*=B$ and
$$
A^*=A\;\iff\;(PBP^{-1})^*=PBP^{-1}\;\iff\; (P^*)^{-1}BP^*=PBP^{-1}\;\iff\;BQ=QB.
$$
I let you check whether the latter is true.

Comment: Pretty calculation!...

Comment: "Let us call P the matrix of the basis E expressed in an orthonormal basis, so that
P∗P==Q" I . I do not understand that. How can u assume there is such a matrix P that is a matrix that transform vectors from the orthonormal representation to E such that if u multiply it by it's adjoint u will get Q. how is it possible ? besides that I understand all the rest.am I wrong thinking on the Functionality of P ?

Comment: @julien thank u very much, but could u explain me the part I did not understand ?

Comment: That's what a Gram matrix is. If $P=\pmatrix{a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2}$, it means that $v_1=a_1e_1+a_2e_2$ where $(e_1,e_2)$ is the orthonormal basis we took. Then the $(1,1)$ element of $P^*P$ is $\overline{a_1}a_1+\overline{a_2}a_2=(v_1,v_1)$. Likewise the $(1,2)$ coefficient is $(v_1,v_2)$ etc...

Comment: @julien I will clarify my question. So I understand what P (transfer vectors from the representation according to E to the representation orthonormal basis). but how can u be sure that P satisfy the eqution P*P=Q ?

Comment: The Gram matrix $Q$ you are given can be written $P^*P$ for any $P$ matrix of $E$ in any orthonormal basis. That's by definition of a Gram matrix.  See my comment above, where I verified it for the $(1,1)$ coefficient. And you don't need an explicit $P$ to answer the question. Actually, you can't find an explicit one as the inner product is not explicit.

Comment: @julien Thank you very much !!